# Turion 64 X2 Mobile Virtualization

Tags: virtualization, vt-x

I have a tablet pc (HP tx2000) with AMD Turion TL-58 and want to use AMD VT  with vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124 to run a Windows XP virtual machine on a Windows Vista Home premium host. The Phoenix BIOS shows that I can enable AMD VT. Will it work with Vmplayer? What are the advantages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean AMD-V. If it is supported then VMware player should work. VMware player however only allows you to use existing virtual machines, not create new ones. If you'd like to create your own as well, look into VMware Server, [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) or [Virtual-PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/). You can find premade VMs of various open source operating systems [here](http://virtualbox.wordpress.com/images/).

As for the advantages, it depends on what you intend to do with virtualization. It can be a learning platform for new operating systems, a sandbox for software development and testing, or even a quick way to test something out without rebooting into a different operating system.

Comment: Thanks... I want to know what are the advantages of AMD VT when I use it with Vmplayer? vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124 does allow creation of virtual machines. i just made one of Windows 2000

Comment: So can I run a 64-bit guest on this 32-bit Vista OS since the underlying processor runs in 64-bit mode and supports the necessary virtualization extensions ? Does the Turion TL-58 support this ?

Answer (score 0):

should try out Microsoft Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0EE2A17F-8538-4619-8D1C-05D27E11ADB2&displaylang=en